# how can i get a collection from an item in another collection that is also a collection

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I would need:

1. a `list(of employee)` that contains all the employees contained in all companies. (e1,e2... e9)
2. the employee how has the oldest DischargeDate higher than 1/1/2018

I have solved it in this way, but I think it can be achieved in a clearer and more efficient way.
Maybe using Linq or/and some lambda expresions

1:

```
     Dim allEmp As New List(Of employee)
        For Each co In Comps
            For Each emplo In co.emp
                allEmp.Add(emplo)
            Next
        Next
```

2:

```
    Dim min As Date = Nothing
        For Each c In Comps
            For Each em In c.emp
                If min = Nothing OrElse (em.DischargeDate > New Date(2018, 1, 1) AndAlso em.DischargeDate < min) Then
                    min = em.DischargeDate
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

I have also tried

```
Dim xxx As List(Of List(Of employee)) = Comps.Select(Function(j) j.emp).ToList
```

But in this way I get a `List(Of List(Of employee))` instead of `List(Of employee)`

these are the classes

```
Public Class company
        Public name As String
        Public emp As List(Of employee)

    End Class

    Public Class employee
        Public name As String
        Public email As String
        Public DischargeDate As Date

    End Class
```

And here the collections

```
        Private Comps As New List(Of company)

        Dim e As List(Of employee)

        Dim e1 As New employee With {.email = "aaa@aaa.aaa", .name = "nameEmp1", .DischargeDate = New Date(2019, 1, 12)}
        Dim e2 As New employee With {.email = "bbb@bbb.bbb", .name = "nameEmp2", .DischargeDate = New Date(2018, 8, 24)}
        Dim e3 As New employee With {.email = "ccc@ccc.ccc", .name = "nameEmp3", .DischargeDate = New Date(2017, 5, 12)}
        e = New List(Of employee) From {{e1}, {e2}, {e3}}
        Comps.Add(New company With {.name = "nameCom1", .emp = e})


        Dim e4 As New employee With {.email = "ddd@ddd.ddd", .name = "nameEmp4", .DischargeDate = New Date(2014, 3, 22)}
        Dim e5 As New employee With {.email = "eee@eee.eee", .name = "nameEmp5", .DischargeDate = New Date(2018, 4, 4)}
        Dim e6 As New employee With {.email = "fff@fff.fff", .name = "nameEmp6", .DischargeDate = New Date(2017, 3, 26)}
        e = New List(Of employee) From {{e4}, {e5}, {e6}}
        Comps.Add(New company With {.name = "nameCom2", .emp = e})



        Dim e7 As New employee With {.email = "ggg@ggg.ggg", .name = "nameEmp7", .DischargeDate = New Date(2019, 1, 8)}
        Dim e8 As New employee With {.email = "hhh@hhh.hhh", .name = "nameEmp8", .DischargeDate = New Date(2018, 6, 30)}
        Dim e9 As New employee With {.email = "iii@iii.iii", .name = "nameEmp9", .DischargeDate = New Date(2017, 2, 26)}
        e = New List(Of employee) From {{e7}, {e8}, {e9}}
        Comps.Add(New company With {.name = "nameCom3", .emp = e})
```

I'll appreciate any suggestion or comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one...

```
    Dim allEmp = (From co In Comps
                  From emplo In co.emp
                  Select emplo).ToList

    For Each emp As employee In allEmp
        Debug.Print(emp.name)
    Next
```

Second one...

```
    Dim dates = (From c In Comps
                 From em In c.emp
                 Where em.DischargeDate > New Date(2018, 1, 1)
                 Select em.DischargeDate)
    Dim minDate = dates.Min
    Debug.Print(minDate.ToString)
```

Comment: both worked perfectly, thank you, it's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This does both:

```
Dim employees = Comps.SelectMany(Function(c) c.emp).ToList()
Dim oldestDischargedEmp As Employee = employees.
          Where(Function(e) e.DischargeDate > #2018-01-01#).
          OrderBy(Function(e) e.DischargeDate).
          First()
```

The main thing to remember is you can use the result from the first part to help you find the answer for the second, and thus avoid duplicating some work.

Also consider removing the `.ToList()` call. You can get by with just the `IEnumerable<T>` a lot more often than you may realize, and doing so can really help performance.

Comment: this also worked perfectly.
Ordering the result so you can just to take the first one has been a great idea, I will keep it in mind for the next time. Thx a lot!!